# Javascript image annotation library

Tags: javascript, image, annotations, editing

I need the ability to crop an image, add arrows, rectangles and text over an image, and maybe blur some area.

Skitch from Evernote is a perfect example of what I'm looking for, however it's a standalone program and what I need is to be able to upload an image(screenshot) to our ticketing system and add some visual annotations and explanations about what's wrong or has to be fixed.

Is anyone aware of such a library so I don't re-invent yet another wheel?

Comment: `->` https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? It's a developer question. I'm not looking for an application, but a javascript library.

Comment: People seem to also ask for libraries there, though I agree that it may not be the best place. However, Stack Overflow isn't the right place for this question either. After all, we have a close reason that says *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Comment: @FelixKling Software Recommendations moderator here. We have fairly strict quality guidelines, so I'd appreciated it if you would link to our [question quality guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/46) whenever you recommend someone re-ask a question on the site. Thanks!

Comment: It's an old question, but my client also was looking for a library to annotate pictures online. I found [easyannotation.net](http://easyannotation.net) library - easy to use and exactly what we were looking for.